# Recording an image through a RTMP Server when the host has stopped their camera

Tags: rtmp, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

**Context**

I have a Live-stream application implemented with [AgoraWebSDK NG](https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/). The application streams to a RTMP server. The application uses [setLiveTranscoding](https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html#setlivetranscoding) method of Agora client to set some configuration for the live streaming, including [transcodingUsers](https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/interfaces/livestreamingtranscodingconfig.html#transcodingusers), which setups the users layouts configuration in the live streaming. During the live streaming, the video is being recorded through the RTMP server, so it can be acceded later as a video asset

**Problem**

If the host has stopped their camera then the RTMP server will record the video with the last image of the host video at the moment they stopped their camera

So, I would like to know what is the necessary configuration to record the live streaming through the RTMP server with an image (user avatar) when the host has stopped their camera

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this @foxhard?